# Sequence point in the assignment operator

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, sequence-points

I already checked some other answers like:

[Sequence point within assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313902/sequence-point-within-assignment-operators)

or

[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735#4183735)

but I have still some doubt about the following part:

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, **and before the value computation of the assignment expression.**

It is not clear for me what is the "value computation of the assignment expression". Is it just (referring to the first link) "show" the number stored in the variable?

Comment: Imagine `h(f() = g());` Here `f()` and `g()` are evaluated first ("left and right operands"), then the assignment takes effect (i.e. the value of `f()` changes), and then the value of the assignment expression is computed.

Comment: Ok. I think (hope) is more clear. I thought that when your f() changes, THAT was the moment of the "value computation". But why is this last passage necessary?

Comment: @andre3312 "value computation" is the value of the expression (which may be viewed by another expression containing this expression); changes to objects are called *side-effects*

Comment: So the value computation of the assignment is just the returning the value for a possible another expression. Is it correct? For example in a = b + c the value computation of the assignment is returning the value of  a.

Comment: `a = b = c + d;` I think the value of the assignment in the second assignement is the value of `b` in this example.

Comment: Ok. Now is more clear.

Comment: So would that imply that the expression `int x=a[a[1]=1]` would be specified as setting a[1] to 1 and yielding that value since the assignment would be sequenced before the outer array subscripting operator?