# XOR operator problems in C

Tags: c, xor

> Which of the following options can achieve a swapping effect for pair `(*, *)`? Note that ^ represents XOR operation. For binary numbers, 0 XOR 0 = 0, 0 XOR 1 = 1, 1 XOR 0 = 1, 1 XOR 1 = 0.
>
> A. `(x, y): x ^= y ^= x ^= y;`
>
> B. `(a[x], a[y]): a[x] ^= a[y] ^= a[x] ^= a[y];`
>
> C. `(x, y): x -= y += x -= y;`
>
> D. `(a[x], a[y]): a[x] -= a[y] += a[x] -= a[y];`

I've seen that C and D are not logically correct. And A is correct I guess. But I'm not sure what's the difference between A and B?

Comment: There's no difference between A an B, they are equivalent. The difference is where the values come from and where they are stored, but the operations themselves are the same. Same with C and D.

Comment: Aren’t most (all?) of these [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475166/are-there-sequence-points-in-the-expression-a-b-a-b-or-is-it-undefined)?

Comment: If this is intended to represent C code then the answer is that they all have undefined behavior. That said, I assume that it's really intended as pseudo-code with other execution rules than C

Comment: What language is this? It's not C. We cannot comment on correctness of pseudo code...

Comment: If `x == y` then swap tricks don’t work with the pair `(a[x], a[y])` even when they’re well-defined, but who knows whether that means they “can” achieve a swapping effect according to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that the equal operations are interpreted from right to left.

**Case A:**

```c
x ^= y ^= x ^= y;
// is equivalent to : x ^= ( y ^= ( x ^= y ) );
// I use indice for each successive value of x and y, x0 and y0 are initial values
// x1 = x0 ^ y0
// y1 = y0 ^ x1 = y0 ^ (x0 ^ y0),
// because ^ operator is associative and commutative, and because X^X is 0
// y1 = x0,                              final value of y is initial value of x
// x2 = x1 ^ y1 = (x0 ^ y0) ^ (x0) = y0  final value of x is initial value of y
```

If x and y are integer variables of same type, the code is valid and swaps x and y

**Case B:**
It is pretty much the same as **A**, `x` and `y` are not modified and are indices in an array. If `a[]` elements are integers, it is valid and swaps 2 items of the array `a` **only if `x` and `y` are different!**
**If `x` and `y` are identical, in `a[x] ^= a[y]`, `a[x]` and `a[y]` are the same l-value, and it is erased losing its initial value.**

**Case C:**

```c
x -= y += x -= y;     // equivalent: x -= ( y += ( x -= y ) );
// x1 = x0 - y0
// y1 = y0 + (x0-y0) = x0
// x2 = x1 - y1 = (x0-y0) - (x0) = -y0, final value of x is the opposite of initial value of y
// to swap value of x and y, we must take the opposite of last x
y += x -= y,  x = y - x;     // this does swap x and y
```

**Case D:**
Same as case **C**, but applies to elements of `a[]` and also has issue if `x` and `y` are identical.

Note:
The equal operator is totally sequenced since C11.
The standard stipulates for assignment (6.5.16)

> The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is
> sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands.

Answer (score -1):

Option A uses XOR operation to swap the values of x and y.
Option B achieves the same result as option A using the XOR operation on **array elements.**

Comment: Unfortunately, while A and B attempt to use XOR to swap values, they fail to be reliable methods for doing so because their behaviors are not defined by the C standard because the updates of the stored values are not sequenced. So it is not correct to say they swap values—they might not and should not be used.

Comment: Any operation between values are equivalent, no matter if it's done between discrete variables or array elements.