# A ^= B ^= A ^= B; unexpected result in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I always thought that A ^= B ^= A ^= B swaps A <-> B. My guess that this line should be evaluated right to left in 3 steps:

```
1) A ^= B;
2) B ^= A;
3) A ^= B;
```

But somehow in C# A becomes 0 if you do it in one line. I've looked into the assembly and found that original A is being stored first and somewhy in the last third step instead of taking the actual current value of A, the code uses cached original value. Assembly looks like this:

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  //eax <- A
mov         dword ptr [ebp-7Ch],eax  //C <- A (why cache?)
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  //eax <- B
xor         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax  //A ^= B
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  //eax <- A
xor         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  //B ^= A
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-7Ch]  //eax <- C (?)
xor         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  //eax ^= B (= C ^ B)
mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax  //A = C ^ B (instead of A ^ B)
```

It seems ok in C++ and assembly is using only 2 variables:

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [a]
xor         eax,dword ptr [b]
mov         dword ptr [a],eax
mov         ecx,dword ptr [b]
xor         ecx,dword ptr [a]
mov         dword ptr [b],ecx
mov         edx,dword ptr [a]
xor         edx,dword ptr [b]
mov         dword ptr [a],edx
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Dunno C#, but potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38421671/3002139

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there a practical application for that code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577140

Comment: Well there is no reason to do that. One time I wanted to seem fancy at code interview and I wrote that swap on a paper. And years later I tried it actually in code just to see if I get things right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ this would be an undefined behavior<sup>*</sup> because of multiple unsequenced assignments.

In C# this is perfectly valid, and zero is the correct result.

To see why consider that XOR ing any number with itself yields zero, because at each sport in the bit pattern there are equal bits. Moreover, XOR order is not important. That's why B ends up with the old value of A, and A ends up being zero.

<sup>*</sup> prior to C++ 17, anyway.

Comment: Yes, thank you all. I've searched badly. Question has been answered already. I'm sorry

Comment: In C++17 changes the sequencing rules around assignment, so be cautious about your claim.